# Looping through nested dict only returns last value unless I assign it to another dict

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, dictionary

I have a dict `products` of the following structure:

```
{'Cheese': {'Cheese': {'comment': 'Markets quiet this week', 'indicator': 'Flat', 'pricelow': '3385', 'priceaverage': '3385', 'pricehigh': '3385'}}, 'MPC': {'MPC70': {'comment': 'Large buyers', 'indicator': 'Flat', 'pricelow': '8598', 'priceaverage': '8929', 'pricehigh': '9039'}, 'MPI:': {'comment': 'Large buyers', 'indicator': 'Flat', 'pricelow': '8598', 'priceaverage': '8929', 'pricehigh': '9039'}, 'MPC85': {'comment': 'Large buyers', 'indicator': 'Flat', 'pricelow': '8598', 'priceaverage': '8929', 'pricehigh': '9039'}}}
```

I would like to resolve the nested structure, for this I want to take the product name "Cheese","MPC70", "MPI", "MPC85", add it to the inner dict as "name" and put all of it in a list. (The category ("Cheese" and "MPC" is not important anymore and will be lost) to have something like this:

```
[{'indicator': 'Flat', 
 'comment': 'Markets quiet this week', 
 'name': 'Cheese', 
 'pricelow': '3385', 
 'priceaverage': '3385', 
 'pricehigh': '3385'}, 
{'indicator': 'Flat', 
 'comment': 'Large buyers.High Ground.', 
 'name': 'MPC70', 
 'pricelow': '4189', 
 'priceaverage': '4409', 
 'pricehigh': '5070'}, 
{'indicator': 'Flat', 
 'comment': 'Large buyers.High Ground.', 
 'name': 'MPI:', 
 'pricelow': '8598', 
 'priceaverage': '8929', 
 'pricehigh': '9039'}, 
{'indicator': 'Flat', 
 'comment': 'Large buyers.High Ground.', 
 'name': 'MPC85', 
 'pricelow': '8377', 
 'priceaverage': '8488', 
 'pricehigh': '8818'}
]
```

So far so good but when I loop thorugh the dictionary for all products in category "MPC", the name is "MPC85"
My loop looks like this:

```
for item in products:
  for subitem in products[item]:
    products[item][subitem]['name'] = subitem
    productlist.append(products[item][subitem])
    #print products[item][subitem]
    #print products[item][subitem]['name']
    #print  item + ' ' + subitem
print productlist
```

For any of the commented print statements, the output is exactly as I want it, however if I print the whole list, the "name" key for each of the "MPC" products is "MPC85"\

After some trial and error and the confirmation of @spectras that the loop actually works, I figured that if I assign the dict to another variable with

```
products2 = products
```

and change the loop to loop over `products2` rather than `products` the whole thing works.

**So the question would be: Why does python seem to have a problem to loop over one dict, while it does it as expected when I assign the dict to another variable?**

EDIT:
A complete dump of what I do and what I get:

```
In [3]: print products
{'Cheese': {'Cheese': {'comment': 'Markets quiet this week', 'indicator': 'Flat', 'pricelow': '3385', 'priceaverage': '3385', 'pricehigh': '3385'}}, 'MPC': {'MPC70': {'comment': 'Large buyers.High Ground.', 'indicator': 'Flat', 'pricelow': '8598', 'priceaverage': '8929', 'pricehigh': '9039'}, 'MPI:': {'comment': 'Large buyers.High Ground.', 'indicator': 'Flat', 'pricelow': '8598', 'priceaverage': '8929', 'pricehigh': '9039'}, 'MPC85': {'comment': 'Large buyers.High Ground.', 'indicator': 'Flat', 'pricelow': '8598', 'priceaverage': '8929', 'pricehigh': '9039'}}, 'Whey Powder': {'Whey Powder': {'comment': 'Dry Whey futures drop', 'indicator': 'Down', 'pricelow': '1124', 'priceaverage': '1124', 'pricehigh': '1124'}}, 'Casein': {'Casein': {'comment': 'No changes.', 'indicator': 'Down', 'pricelow': '7165', 'priceaverage': '7605', 'pricehigh': '8157'}}, 'Lactose': {'Lactose': {'comment': 'Lactose prices remain unchanged', 'indicator': 'Down', 'pricelow': '683', 'priceaverage': '683', 'pricehigh': '683'}}, 'Powders': {'NFDM': {'comment': 'Export volumes dropped.', 'indicator': 'Up', 'pricelow': '2408', 'priceaverage': '2408', 'pricehigh': '2408'}}, 'Caseinate': {'Caseinate': {'comment': 'actively selling.requested pricing.', 'indicator': 'Down', 'pricelow': '7716', 'priceaverage': '8598', 'pricehigh': '9479'}}, 'Cream': {'Butter': {'comment': 'Butter stocks increased', 'indicator': 'Down', 'pricelow': '3847', 'priceaverage': '3847', 'pricehigh': '3847'}}, 'WPC': {'WPC80': {'comment': 'WPC 80 \xe2\x80\x93 Supply continues.', 'indicator': 'Down', 'pricelow': '5300', 'priceaverage': '7165', 'pricehigh': '8267'}, 'IWPC80': {'comment': 'WPC 80 \xe2\x80\x93 Supply continues.', 'indicator': 'Down', 'pricelow': '5300', 'priceaverage': '7165', 'pricehigh': '8267'}}}

In [4]: %paste
        for item in products:
                for subitem in products[item]:
                        products[item][subitem]['name'] = subitem
                        #print products[item][subitem]
                        #print products[item][subitem]['name']
                        productlist.append(products[item][subitem])
                        #print  item + ' ' + subitem
                        #print products[item][subitem]['name']
                        #print products[item]
                        #print products[item][subitem]
        print productlist

## -- End pasted text --
[{'comment': 'Markets quiet this week', 'indicator': 'Flat', 'name': 'Cheese', 'pricelow': '3385', 'priceaverage': '3385', 'pricehigh': '3385'}, {'comment': 'Large buyers.High Ground.', 'indicator': 'Flat', 'name': 'MPC85', 'pricelow': '8598', 'priceaverage': '8929', 'pricehigh': '9039'}, {'comment': 'Large buyers.High Ground.', 'indicator': 'Flat', 'name': 'MPC85', 'pricelow': '8598', 'priceaverage': '8929', 'pricehigh': '9039'}, {'comment': 'Large buyers.High Ground.', 'indicator': 'Flat', 'name': 'MPC85', 'pricelow': '8598', 'priceaverage': '8929', 'pricehigh': '9039'}, {'comment': 'Dry Whey futures drop', 'indicator': 'Down', 'name': 'Whey Powder', 'pricelow': '1124', 'priceaverage': '1124', 'pricehigh': '1124'}, {'comment': 'No changes.', 'indicator': 'Down', 'name': 'Casein', 'pricelow': '7165', 'priceaverage': '7605', 'pricehigh': '8157'}, {'comment': 'Lactose prices remain unchanged', 'indicator': 'Down', 'name': 'Lactose', 'pricelow': '683', 'priceaverage': '683', 'pricehigh': '683'}, {'comment': 'Export volumes dropped.', 'indicator': 'Up', 'name': 'NFDM', 'pricelow': '2408', 'priceaverage': '2408', 'pricehigh': '2408'}, {'comment': 'actively selling.requested pricing.', 'indicator': 'Down', 'name': 'Caseinate', 'pricelow': '7716', 'priceaverage': '8598', 'pricehigh': '9479'}, {'comment': 'Butter stocks increased', 'indicator': 'Down', 'name': 'Butter', 'pricelow': '3847', 'priceaverage': '3847', 'pricehigh': '3847'}, {'comment': 'WPC 80 \xe2\x80\x93 Supply continues.', 'indicator': 'Down', 'name': 'IWPC80', 'pricelow': '5300', 'priceaverage': '7165', 'pricehigh': '8267'}, {'comment': 'WPC 80 \xe2\x80\x93 Supply continues.', 'indicator': 'Down', 'name': 'IWPC80', 'pricelow': '5300', 'priceaverage': '7165', 'pricehigh': '8267'}]

In [5]: type(products)
Out[5]: dict

In [6]: type(products['Cheese']
   ...: )
Out[6]: dict
```

Edit2:
Ran suggested snipped from comments, output:

```
    In [3]: print products
{'Cheese': {'Cheese': {'comment': 'Markets quiet this week', 'indicator': 'Flat', 'pricelow': '3385', 'priceaverage': '3385', 'pricehigh': '3385'}}, 'MPC': {'MPC70': {'comment': 'Large buyers.High Ground.', 'indicator': 'Flat', 'pricelow': '8598', 'priceaverage': '8929', 'pricehigh': '9039'}, 'MPI:': {'comment': 'Large buyers.High Ground.', 'indicator': 'Flat', 'pricelow': '8598', 'priceaverage': '8929', 'pricehigh': '9039'}, 'MPC85': {'comment': 'Large buyers.High Ground.', 'indicator': 'Flat', 'pricelow': '8598', 'priceaverage': '8929', 'pricehigh': '9039'}}, 'Whey Powder': {'Whey Powder': {'comment': 'Dry Whey futures drop', 'indicator': 'Down', 'pricelow': '1124', 'priceaverage': '1124', 'pricehigh': '1124'}}, 'Casein': {'Casein': {'comment': 'No changes.', 'indicator': 'Down', 'pricelow': '7165', 'priceaverage': '7605', 'pricehigh': '8157'}}, 'Lactose': {'Lactose': {'comment': 'Lactose prices remain unchanged', 'indicator': 'Down', 'pricelow': '683', 'priceaverage': '683', 'pricehigh': '683'}}, 'Powders': {'NFDM': {'comment': 'Export volumes dropped.', 'indicator': 'Up', 'pricelow': '2408', 'priceaverage': '2408', 'pricehigh': '2408'}}, 'Caseinate': {'Caseinate': {'comment': 'actively selling.requested pricing.', 'indicator': 'Down', 'pricelow': '7716', 'priceaverage': '8598', 'pricehigh': '9479'}}, 'Cream': {'Butter': {'comment': 'Butter stocks increased', 'indicator': 'Down', 'pricelow': '3847', 'priceaverage': '3847', 'pricehigh': '3847'}}, 'WPC': {'WPC80': {'comment': 'WPC 80 \xe2\x80\x93 Supply continues.', 'indicator': 'Down', 'pricelow': '5300', 'priceaverage': '7165', 'pricehigh': '8267'}, 'IWPC80': {'comment': 'WPC 80 \xe2\x80\x93 Supply continues.', 'indicator': 'Down', 'pricelow': '5300', 'priceaverage': '7165', 'pricehigh': '8267'}}}

In [4]: %paste
from pprint import pprint; from itertools import chain; pprint([(key, type(val).__name__, id(val)) for key, val in chain.from_iterable(x.items() for x in products.values())])

## -- End pasted text --
[('Cheese', 'dict', 64885352L),
 ('MPC70', 'dict', 64887800L),
 ('MPI:', 'dict', 64887800L),
 ('MPC85', 'dict', 64887800L),
 ('Whey Powder', 'dict', 65061480L),
 ('Casein', 'dict', 65061752L),
 ('Lactose', 'dict', 65062024L),
 ('NFDM', 'dict', 65062296L),
 ('Caseinate', 'dict', 65062568L),
 ('Butter', 'dict', 65063112L),
 ('WPC80', 'dict', 65062840L),
 ('IWPC80', 'dict', 65062840L)]
```

Comment: The code you posted actually works. You probably did not post what you have exactly.

Comment: I just tried it again, checked if my dict looks like I showed and used the code I posted here, the problem persists.

Comment: @Alexander. Check again. The sample in your question is not a valid dict - but if it's fixed, the loop works as expected. Copy and paste your **real** code, not something you think looks like it.

Comment: The code you posted, in a python file: https://gist.github.com/spectras/0f50994c7086fb139567 Runs perfectly on both python2 and python3.

Comment: I added the real dictionary. @spectras I can confirm that your code works, however it does not with my dict. So I looks like there is an error there.

Comment: Same: copy-paste your dict into the python file and run it, still works fine. I guess your datastructure, whatever it is, is not actually a dict. It must be some dict-like datastructure, probably from some kind of data framework. Without further detail it is impossible to tell what is wrong.

Comment: @spectras So I added a complete dump from the shell. The dicts are actually dicts and I don't use anything else but the standard python structures. I also restarted the shell to make sure that there isn't "old" data in any of the variables etc.

Comment: Try throwing in this just before [4]: `from pprint import pprint; from itertools import chain; pprint([(key, type(val).__name__, id(val)) for key, val in chain.from_iterable(x.items() for x in products.values())])`

Comment: Ran your snippet after restarting shell again, output is in the post.

Comment: @spectras I just "solved" it by using `products2 = products` and running the loop over the dict products2. With this everything works as expected. Any idea why that would solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, the problem is now clear.

Explanation on the sample line I made you copy-paste:

```
from pprint import pprint
from itertools import chain
pprint([(key, type(val).__name__, id(val))
        for key, val in chain.from_iterable(x.items() for x in products.values())])
```

This goes through each 2-nd level dictionary and prints:

1. The key used to access it.
2. The type of the dictionary (to make sure it was actually a dict)
3. The unique identifier of the dictionary.

So given those results, there is something important to notice:

```
   [('Cheese', 'dict', 64885352L),
     ('MPC70', 'dict', 64887800L),
     ('MPI:', 'dict', 64887800L),
     ('MPC85', 'dict', 64887800L),
     ('Whey Powder', 'dict', 65061480L),
     ('Casein', 'dict', 65061752L),
     ('Lactose', 'dict', 65062024L),
     ('NFDM', 'dict', 65062296L),
     ('Caseinate', 'dict', 65062568L),
     ('Butter', 'dict', 65063112L),
     ('WPC80', 'dict', 65062840L),
     ('IWPC80', 'dict', 65062840L)]
```

→ Some of your products share the same dict. See how MPC70, MPI, and MPC85 have the same unique identifier?

As a result, instead of adding three different dicts, each with its added `name` to your product list, you end up adding the same dict three times, overwriting the `name` with each loop iteration.

This also explains why copy-pasting changed the issue. When copy-pasting, you create three different dicts, that just happen to look the same.

We can now fix your code, knowing it *must* explicitly copy the products instead of simply re-using them:

```
for item in products:
  for subitem in products[item]:
    product = products[item][subitem].copy()
    product['name'] = subitem
    productlist.append(product)
```

As a bonus, the same loop written a bit more efficiently:

```
for item in products.values():
  for subkey, subitem in item.items():
    product = subitem.copy()
    product['name'] = subkey
    productlist.append(product)
```

Comment: Great, that solves the problem a bit more elegantly. Is there a way to resolve it at the source, ie. create the dicts differently that I don't run into the same problem again? I create them with nested for-loops and `products[product][productname] = {}` and the assignment `products[product][productname]['indicator'] = indicator` in the innermost loop

Comment: Well, that would need the whole loop code to know for sure. Probably you create the dict in the outer loop and assign it in the inner loop, so you end up assigning the same dictionary for every sub-item. Just remember that in python, when you do `x = y`, you don't copy `y`, you just copy the reference, so `x` and `y` point at the same object. When you need an actual copy, you must do it explicitly. For instance, `x = list(y)` (for lists) or `x = y.copy()` (for dicts).

Comment: I will keep that in mind. From my understanding I refer to a new dict in every loop; but if it works with your loop, it's good enough for this project. Thanks